# How to remove default space between columns in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to remove space between this columns? I marked by red color space I want to remove, it should be sticky, I guess. Is it possible?

[image]

My code for trying to do this:

```
 child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Checkbox(
                            checkColor: Colors.green,
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            value: value,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              value = value;
                            }),
                        Text(
                          'One',
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Checkbox(
                            checkColor: Colors.green,
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            value: value,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              value = value;
                            }),
                        Text(
                          'two',
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code and add [**`visualDensity`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/visualDensity.html) in your [**`Checkbox`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) widget

**visualDensity -** *Its define checkbox's layout*

```
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
                visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                checkColor: Colors.green,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                value: value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  value = value;
                }),
            Text(
              'One',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
                visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                checkColor: Colors.green,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                value: value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  value = value;
                }),
            Text(
              'two',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not `Column` issue. You got the space from `checkbox`. Just wrap your `checkbox` with `sizebox` and give them a specific height.

```
        Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              child: Checkbox(
                  checkColor: Colors.green,
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  value: value,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    value = value;
                  }),
            ),
            Text(
              'One',
              //    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              child: Checkbox(
                  checkColor: Colors.green,
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  value: value,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    value = value;
                  }),
            ),
            Text(
              'two',
              //   style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ])
```